# What "register new user" solution for JASPIC JDBC realm authentication?

Tags: java, authentication, jakarta-ee, jdbc, jaspic

I've created my own JDBC realm (using WildFly 8.2) as described at paragraph [50.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/security-advanced003.htm#BABEJJDE) of the JavaEE 7 tutorial. My understanding is that JDBC realm authentication implies that user credentials are read and checked by the server, the application doesn't even know the coordinates for the auth-reserved DB.

For a "new user sign up", the only thing I can imagine is to implement a classic solution from the inside of my application: accessing auth DB, check if chosen username is already present, insert row in the table... but doesn't this violate the whole paradigm of "container managed authentication", and maybe insert security holes?

Is there some server-implemented mechanism that I ignore?

Answer (score 3):

> but doesn't this violates the whole paradigm of "container managed authentication", and maybe insert security holes?

Yes, more or less. The container managed security concept, where the application is totally unaware of the authentication mechanism and the identity store (location where the user data is actually stored) doesn't really take the use case into account where an application has its own user sign up/register functionality.

The idea seems to be more intended for integrating externally obtained applications (e.g. say a Sonar or JIRA instance) into an existing enterprise structure. There the users are created by an admin using a central system like LDAP, or in some situations even an admin UI of the application server.

Unfortunately *many* of your typical public web applications aren't of this variety. They are standalone apps (don't integrate with existing internal enterprise infrastructure) and they effectively manage their own users.

The classical concept is an ill fit there, and that's why the Java EE Security EG is currently exploring how to best address this.

You basically have three "solutions" in the mean time:

1. Just define your DB connection details twice, once at the server level, once at the app. It looks like you were indeed already doing this.
2. Use JASPIC, which is a container provided authentication API which has the option to let the application contain the auth module. It can use the exact same data source and possible JPA entity manager and such that the application is also using.
3. Do your security using an external security framework, e.g. DeltaSpike Security or Shiro, that's totally implemented in "user space".

From a Java EE perspective, none is really ideal. The first has the duplicate definition and indeed somewhat violates the principle, the second is by itself okay, but JASPIC is a tad low level, and the second is a rich solution but doesn't integrate well with existing Java EE security.